# Unknown attribute error on CSV upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, csv, model-view-controller, upload

I am trying to upload a CSV file into an existing database and receiving the following

> error: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in UploadsController#import! Validation failed: Email has already been taken.

**Controller**:

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @uploads = Upload.all
  end

  def import
    Upload.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to uploads_path, notice: "Employee data imported!"
  end
end
```

**Model**:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'csv'

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Employee.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

**Table**:

```
create_table "employees", force: :cascade do |t| 
  t.string "last_name" 
  t.string "first_name" 
  t.string "employee_code" 
  t.string "email" 
  t.string "level" 
  t.string "dept" 
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false 
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false 
end
```

I checked and and my database headers for employees do match my first row of the CSV file (beginning row 1, col 1).  Any thoughts?

Comment: You can add migration to add new attribute `last_name` to employees table.

Comment: Also double check the database you're running the upload against is the same database you're manually checking for the columns....ie, if you added the column recently to development and it's not on production yet, etc.

Comment: Thanks @MuhamadAkbarBinWidayat. See below. I have `last_name` as a column in my table.  Unless I'm missing something not sure what to do.

Comment: @jarlyon Do you have a uniqueness validation for `email` on your `Employee` model? It does not appear in your post but the error is caused by attempting to insert a duplicate value on a unique column.

Comment: thanks @DRSE. that worked!! But i don't really understand why if I had an empty database. there shouldnt have been emails in there to not be unique?

Comment: Are you sure the database is empty before attempting the upload? From `rails c` run `Employee.count` - is the result 0? Are there duplicate e-mails appearing in the upload file? Are you doing anything to reset the state of your database each time before attempting the upload? Are you doing this in development or test?

Comment: @jarlyon Did my answer below solve your problem? If so, can you please mark it as the accepted answer?  As a sidenote, you radically changed your question from the original, making most of my original answer irrelevant.  To keep better track of changes to your question in the future you should add an EDIT section to express changes/additions to your main question as I have done with my answer.

Comment: sorry @DRSE! Yes this helped. Sorry new to the site so not familiar with the etiquette yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys of the hash you supply to `Employee.create!` (the CSV headers in this case) need to match exactly with the names of attributes on your model.  Your problem is probably caused by one or more of the following:

- There is a column where the header is not all lowercase. E.g., the CSV column name may be "Email" or "EMAIL" but should be "email".
- There is a column where the header has spaces in it. E.g., the CSV column name may be "first name" or "last name" but should be "first_name" or "last_name", respectively.
- There is a column in the CSV in which the column header is misspelled or otherwise doesn't belong to your table schema in the db at all. (Though you have said all of your CSV column headers match the database table columns, maybe check again if the problem is not solved by the first two bullets.)

Any one of these will cause the `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError` you are seeing. If the problem is being caused by one or multiple of the above then you can obviously solve the problem by editing your CSV file to make sure every header is lowercase with underscores instead of spaces.  Alternatively, you could pass in the `:header_converters => :symbol` option to `CSV.foreach` like this:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
  Employee.create! row.to_hash
end
```

This option will transform your headers by converting them to lowercase, replacing spaces with underscores, and then converting them to symbols. This may be a more reliable option if you have a lot of column headers to tidy up, or if you will frequently receive the files with "slightly bad" headers suffering from one of the problems described above.

**EDIT**

I see you updated your question with more detail about the error.  Rails is telling you that there is a column with header "last_name" in your CSV but there is no such column in your database (i.e. no such attribute on your `Employee` model). As Muhamad suggested, you could create a migration to add the `last_name` column to `Employee`.  Can you verify that your employees table in the database has this column?

Comment: thanks @drse. i tried Thanks -- I added `:header_converters => :symbol` now get a different error. see my initial post for new error and table